# MySql auto increment stopped at 255

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to find out the reason why it was stopped at `255`. But I don't know.
Can you please help?

I deleted all data and tried to execute, no more data is saved on DB.

[Browse](https://khalomsky.000webhostapp.com/255.PNG)

[Structure](https://khalomsky.000webhostapp.com/2551.PNG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the data type of the column to an `int` data type

TINYINT:

> It is a whole number with or without a sign. With sign the range of
>   valid values ​​goes from -128 to 127. Without sign, the range of
>   values ​​is from 0 to 255

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Thank you so much Palacio. It is working. :-)  Have a nice day.